# Unable to connect phone to pc. Phone charges only

Tags: adb, fastboot, connection-issues, usb-connection-mode, android-pc

**My phone model is Huawei G7-L11. Android version is 6.0**

Hey there, I want to connect my phone to PC to be able to unlock its bootloader. When I connect to PC, It charges only and that's it.

**What I did:**

1: I tried to connect to pc using Huawei HiSuit but that didn't worked. It does not show anything to PC or mobile as well, just charges the phone. I tried to connect another Huawei phone and that succeeded to connect to PC, But my Huawei G7 is not connecting to pc... Yes of course I turned on the USB debugging as well as allow hdb thing, I also disabled it and re-enabled it but that also didn't worked.

2: I tried to use adb to detect my phone... I typed `adb devices` as well as `fastboot devices` but that also didn't shown my devices.

**Note:** yes I know about MTP and other options, But my device is not connecting at all to PC.. It is not showing any option either. Just charges. I Installed the Huawei G7 drivers as well as snapdragon driver + universal ad drivers. I am 100% sure my USB cable is fine and I am not using any USB hub.

Please Help me... I want to unlock bootloader... Help me connect my device to PC.

Comment: replace the usb connector with spare part from aliexpress

Answer (score 1):

First of all, start with easy-to-solve debugging:

- Have you unlocked your phone while trying to connect to PC or did you connect with the screensaver showing?
- After unlocking, you have a tab (in most of the phones its on top) that you can show by sliding down. There, you have a notification about the connection. Have you clicked it and set it to file transfer instead of just charging?
- Try changing the USB cable.

**Note:** I know this could be answered by commenting the question but I haven't got enough reputation in this website.

Comment: first of all thnk u for your answer.. yes I know about the usb transfer thing but it does not show notification.. it does nothing else then charging..

Comment: And have you tried a different USB cable and a different USB port (on the PC)?